# Find maximum number of nodes in a regular graph of degree 4 and diameter 2

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In $n$ nodes directed graph, every vertex has in-degree and out-degree equal to $4$.
If every vertex is reachable from every other vertex directed by a path of length at most $2$.
How can we find maximum value of $n$?

Comment: A rather poor upper bound is $21$ since every vertex can reach at most $4$ vertices and each of those at most $4$, so $1+4+16$ is an upper bound, but I am pretty sure it isn't sharp

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $20$. To construct an example with $n=20$, take the graph whose vertices are all pairs $(p,q)$ with different $p,q\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and assume there is an edge from $(i,j)$ to $(k,l)$ if and only if $j=k$. It is clear that $(i,j)\to(j,k)\to(k,l)$ is a path from $(i,j)$ to $(k,l)$ if $j\neq k$.

Clearly, the number of vertices that can be attained from certain $u$ by paths of length $k$ is at most $\mathrm{outdegree}^k$, so that the upper bound is $4^0+4^1+4^2=21$. (Actually, this was a comment by Jorge Fernández.) To see that this bound cannot be attained is harder, see [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009589568090091X) for the proof.

Comment: With formula upper bound is 21, why the answer is 20.

Comment: Because $n=21$ is impossible, see the reference. The example with $n=20$ is above.